# Git reports branch as up-to-date when it is not

Tags: git

I am trying to understand why Git reports by branch being up to date when it is not

My "dev" branch is the branch I am working with, and after I checkout to this branch I get this message: `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'`

So I presumed that if I performed a pull that no files would be updated

However, when I then perform a pull, numerous files are updated, so it seems that my branch is not up to date at all!

What am I missing here, or why does it report this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`origin/dev` can be thought of as a *snapshot* of the remote repository from the last time you ran `git fetch` or `git pull`.

Git is telling you the truth - your local branch is up to date with the current *snapshot*. However, when
you run `git pull`, two things happen:

- It fetches a new snapshot from the remote repository. This becomes the new `origin/dev` on your machine.
  At this point, it may no longer be true that your local branch is up to date with `origin/dev`.
- It tries to merge the changes from the (now updated) `origin/dev` into your branch.

You should be able to correct this by running a `git fetch` before trying to discern if your local branch is up to date with the remote.